# Incorrect output for string manipulation

Tags: string

The purpose of this program is to find the first instance of a vowel in a word, remove all the consonants that came before said vowel, append them to the back of the word and then append "ay". I don't know why it's not working for word = "hello". vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]. All letters were changed to lower case for comparison.

```
        # First for loop: Runs through every letter in the word
        for i in range(len(word)):

            # Second For loop: Runs through every vowel in vowel list
            for j in range(len(vowels)):

                # Checks if letter is vowel
                if word[i] == vowels[j]:

                    # Records index
                    first_vowel_index = i

                    # Objective complete, exit loop
                    break

        # Removes consonants from beginning of word, adds them to the end and appends "ay"
        word_pig_latin = word[first_vowel_index:] + word[:first_vowel_index] + "ay"
```

Comment: Hint: which loop do you break at _'Objective complete, exit loop'_?

Comment: ohhh, thanks so much!!!